# Method for Energy Computation of Protein Structures

Tags: molecular-dynamics, reference-request, proteins, energy

So far i have found only one paper that describes how we can compute protein energy while doing MD simulation:

- [Nishikawa, Ken, Motohisa Oobatake, and Tatsuo Ooi. "***Method for Energy Computation of Protein Structures: A Set of Amino Acid Geometries and Energy Parameters*** (Commemoration Issue Dedicated to Professor Tatsuo Yamamoto on the Occasion of his Retirement)." Bulletin of the Institute for Chemical Research, Kyoto University 58.3 (1980): 308-322.](https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/76901/1/chd058_3_308.pdf)

Can you propose more papers for protein energy computation?

Comment: I don't get the issue here. For each step in MD, you can get the system energy calculated with the used force field. Nothing new here. BUT, if you want to calculate the binding free energy between the ligand and the protein, it is also possible but in general using a third party software.

Comment: @Camps, I didn't get your comment. can you rephrase it?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "protein energy". Do you mean the total potential energy of all internal protein interactions? The total energy (including solvent interactions and kinetic energy)? Binding energy between a protein and ligand? Or some free energy, which includes pressure and entropy terms?

Comment: @HaydenS if it's the mass-equivalence energy, that's particularly straightforward. You just multiply by the speed of light squared and you get 2e10 kcal/mol/Dalton. :)